# Filter All Objects That Belongs To a User From ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I have two models

```
class MyClients(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    client_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    client_address=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)


class MyIvoice(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    my_client=models.ForeignKey(MyClients)
```

In the form, all objects in the foreignkey (MyClients) will display but I only want to filter the names of client listed by the user not all the clients in the Myclient model. How can I carry this out in models?

I understand tha I can do this in views but can it be done in models? Since I want the user to select one client in the form.

Comment: So there can be multiple records in `MyClients` for any given user, correct?

Comment: Is you real question "how to have the user object in the django form?"

Comment: Do it in the form, not in the model

Comment: @christophe31 yeah, that's the real question

Comment: @wim how cam I carry that out in form?

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct to do this on the model, you want to do it on the form.

If you already know the user instance for the form, you can do it at the class level with the `queryset` kwarg (when you are defining the field):

```
client = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyClients.objects.filter(user=my_user))
```

However, if you only have access to the user instance at the create time, then you can still override the queryset later (usually in `__init__`):

```
self.fields['client'].queryset = MyClients.objects.filter(user=my_user)
```

Comment: Should it be placed in models or under modelform?

Comment: This is in your form.  i.e. inside some class you have defined which inherits from `django.forms.Form`

Comment: thanks, will give it a try as soon as I get home. And I will update

Comment: I tried your method client = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyClients.objects.filter(user=User)) but the form field is blank, it didn't return any user objects. Any idea?

Comment: Looks like you may have used the `User` model class not a `user` instance

Comment: You mean I should do myclients__user ?

Answer (score 1):

In the form part add a **init** function:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form, FormMixin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        self.user = user
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # do stuff
        self.fields['myclient'].queryset = user.myclient_set.all()
```

Then in the view part add `user=request.user` as form arg.

```
def my_view(request, id=None):
    # do stuff to get your instance
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance, user=request.user)
```

Comment: this user=request.user should be in the views, right?

Comment: indeed, `form = MyForm(request.POST or None, user=request.user)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the related name:

```
# Gets all MyClient objects for a user
user.myclient_set.all()
```

I'm not entirely sure why you want to do this on the model, the place for this sort of logic is the form.

Comment: how can I carry this out in form?

Comment: see @wim's answer. What you will need to do is pass the user object into the form when you initialise it.